# Working out the Tag, Block and Word Offset fields

Tags: caching, memory-management, computer-science, cpu-architecture

A byte addressable computer with **15-bit addresses**
A **cache** capable of storing **2k bytes of data** and **blocks of 8 bytes**

if the memory address is **direct-mapped**, How can you work out the number of bits needed for the **Tag**, **Block** and **Word Offset fields**?

Answer (score 1):

The offset has to address all the byte-positions in a block, so you need log2(8) = 3 bits for that.

There are 2k/8 = 256 sets (each set containing only 1 block because it's direct mapped), so log2(256) = 8 bits for the index (or block, as you're calling it, but may be confusing).

Tag is the rest. 15 - 8 - 3 = 4 bits left over for the tag.